# Sufficient condition for absolute continuity

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that f is continuous on [a,b], f'(x) exists for almost every x\in (a,b), and f'(x) integrable. Prove that f is absolutely continuous.  Particularly, if f is a log-concave function, the is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

This is false. The Cantor function is a counterexample.

Comment: Thank you! if f is a log-concave function, is it correct?

Comment: Why the down vote? Seems like a clear and simple answer to me.

Comment: If \phi(x) is a convex function on (a,b) and \phi approximates +\infty when x approximates the boundary of (a,b), then the log-concave function f=e^{-\phi} is absolutely continuous on [a,b] if let f(a)=f(b)=0.

Answer (score 0):

The following theorem is maybe useful:

Theorem 3.3. Banach-Zaretsky theorem. Let f ∈ BV ([a,b]) be a continuous
function. Then f is absolutely continuous on [a,b] if and only if
m(A) =0 ⇒ m(f(A)) = 0. where m(A) denote the Lebesgue measure of A.

I can prove that f=e^{-\phi} is continuous on [a,b] and f\in BV([a,b]) (f is monotonous increasing first, then monotonous decreasing on [a,b]), I don't know how to prove
m(A) =0 ⇒ m(f(A)) = 0 (map 0 Lebesgue measure set A to 0 Lebesgue measure set f(A)).